# MVC5 slideshow - how to use Colorbox or is there better alternative?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, colorbox

This is my first attempt to use Colorbox in an MVC application and it looks like routing is tripping me up. In the Colorbox sample code the image is set up as a link. In this case the slideshow property is set to true to Colorbox should iterate over the all the images with the specified class. Slide/link looks like this:

```
<a class="slideshow" href="~/Content/Images/slideshow/lk_03.jpg" title="Foobar at night"></a>
```

Of course when I click on that link I get a 404 error because it tries to navigate to Content/Images/slideshow/lk_03.jpg rather than displaying the image.

My script code and links are directly from the Colorbox sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following, where images were directly placed in the 'Content' folder.

```
<h2>Fade Transition</h2>
<p><a class="colorbox" href="../Content/img1.jpg" title="Image 1">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
<p><a class="colorbox" href="../Content/img2.jpg" title="Image 2"></a></p>
<p><a class="colorbox" href="../Content/img3.jpg" title="Image 3"></a></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".colorbox").colorbox({ rel: 'colorbox', transition: "fade" });
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I updated the script and link and now it just opens the image on a blank page. However that is progress. I'll keep working on this and report progress.

Comment: Ok, couple of other things that might help, make sure including jquery.colorbox.js after the jquery-version script you are using. Also ensure you are including the colorbox.css from examples.

Comment: Check, check and check on the above Jimmy. Still opens as a static image in a new page. I'm going to build something out in isolation and try to get it working. If that doesn't work I'll post the code for the entire view here and see if you can identify the flaw. Thanks again.